# How to convert List to Map using Java Stream API?

Tags: java, java-stream, grouping, collectors

I need to convert `List` of `POJO` to `Map<Integer, List<MyClass>>` where the key is the value from `MyClass` That is the following code looks like this:

```
public class MyClass {
    public int id;         // this field value must be key of map.
    public String name;
}

public static void main(String... args) {
    List<MyClass> lst = new ArrayList();
    lst.add(new MyClass(1, "John"));
    lst.add(new MyClass(1, "Peter"));
    lst.add(new MyClass(2, "Sarah"));

    Map<Integer, List<MyClass>> res = lst.collect(..);
}
```

How can I do this? Can you help me?

Comment: and what would be key of Map<Integer, List<MyClass>>, in case you are planning for id of MyClass, you tend to lose data due to duplicate key

Comment: @ShaileshChandra nope, one can groupBy and for each duplicate `id`, the entity would be added to the list as the corresponding value of the map.

Comment: @Naman got it , actually I read target as **Map<Integer, MyClass >** my bad

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that using `groupingBy`:

```
Map<Integer, List<MyClass>> res = lst.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(MyClass::getId));
```

*Aside*: Minor correction in the existing code, avoid unchecked assignments using:

```
List<MyClass> lst = new ArrayList<>();
```